# how to convert post values form '_' to '.' in php

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $CUSTOMER_ID=($_POST['customerid']);
    $CUST_TYPE = ($_POST['customer_type']);
    $APP_DATE=( $_POST['input_date']);
    $PRODUCT_ID = ( $_POST['productid']);
    $ACTION = ($_POST['new_loan']);
    $CURRENCY= ($_POST['currency']);
    $LOAN_PURPOSE = ( $_POST['loan_purpose']);
    $AA_SECTOR= ( $_POST['aa_sector']);
    $GU_RECORD_ID=( $_POST['record_id']);
    $DISB_ACCOUNT = ( $_POST['disb_account']);
    $REPAY_ACCOUNT= ( $_POST['repay_account']);
    $CHARGE_ACCOUNT=($_POST['charge_account']);
```

I want to convert my values to have '.' eg.  $CUSTOMER_ID to $CUSTOMER.ID, CUST_TYPE to CUST.TYPE

Comment: You mean you want a variable named `$CUSTOMER.ID`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = 'CUST_TYPE';
$pattern = '/_/';
$replacement = '.';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);

echo $result;
```

gives:

```
CUST.TYPE
```

so the quick and dirty solution is:

```
$pattern = '/_/';
$replacement = '.';

$CUSTOMER_ID=($_POST['customerid']);
$CUST_TYPE = ($_POST['customer_type']);
$APP_DATE=( $_POST['input_date']);
$PRODUCT_ID = ( $_POST['productid']);
$ACTION = ($_POST['new_loan']);
$CURRENCY= ($_POST['currency']);
$LOAN_PURPOSE = ( $_POST['loan_purpose']);
$AA_SECTOR= ( $_POST['aa_sector']);
$GU_RECORD_ID=( $_POST['record_id']);
$DISB_ACCOUNT = ( $_POST['disb_account']);
$REPAY_ACCOUNT= ( $_POST['repay_account']);
$CHARGE_ACCOUNT=($_POST['charge_account']);

$CUSTOMER_ID= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $CUSTOMER_ID);
$CUST_TYPE = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $CUST_TYPE);
$APP_DATE= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $APP_DATE);
$PRODUCT_ID = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $PRODUCT_ID);
$ACTION = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $ACTION);
$CURRENCY= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $CURRENCY);
$LOAN_PURPOSE = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $LOAN_PURPOSE);
$AA_SECTOR= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $AA_SECTOR);
$GU_RECORD_ID= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $GU_RECORD_ID);
$DISB_ACCOUNT = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $DISB_ACCOUNT);
$REPAY_ACCOUNT= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $REPAY_ACCOUNT);
$CHARGE_ACCOUNT= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $CHARGE_ACCOUNT);
```